# Protractor handshake failed when connecting to local server with https protocol

Tags: protractor, angular-cli, e2e-testing

I am trying to write protractor test but my application connects to WLS server which uses TEST certificates to authenticate for further communication.

I have no option for webdriver update because of my company policy.So I have downloaded chrome driver and using it.

Protractor : 5.4.2

Chrome: 74.0.3729.169

Chrome Driver: chromedriver_74.0.3729.6_win32

```
// Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
// https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

const {SpecReporter} = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 30000,
  chromeDriver: '../lib/chromedriver_74.0.3729.6_win32.exe',
  specs: [
    './src/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'acceptInsecureCerts': true,
    'acceptSslCerts': true,
    chromeOptions: {
      useAutomationExtension: false,
      args: ['--headless']
    }
  },
  framework: 'jasmine',
  directConnect: true,
  troubleshoot: true,
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showTiming: true,
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 2500000,
    print: function () {
    }
  },
  onPrepare: function () {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.e2e.json')
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({spec: {displayStacktrace: true}}));
  }
};
```

But I am getting error as below:

> [0712/104633.475:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(946)] handshake
>   failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -117
>   [0712/104633.548:INFO:CONSOLE(27396)] "Http failure response for
>   https://localhost:25000/app/api/disciplines: 0 Unknown Error", source:
>   http://localhost:8082/app/main.js (27396)

Comment: How do you run tests? What do you have in the `angular.json`? Could it be related to CORS?

Comment: No,its not CORS. Its not getting the test certificate for authenticate I feel so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by using the following method :

[AutoSelectCertificateForUrls](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AutoSelectCertificateForUrls)

By editing the registry, I was able to stop the popup and do auto-select and could run my test successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the `--allow-insecure-localhost` and/or the `--ignore-certificate-errors` to the `args` array.

```
  chromeOptions: {
    args: [
      '--headless',
      '--ignore-certificate-errors',
      '--allow-insecure-localhost'
    ]
  }
```